# Querying County Open data endpoint and filtering by radius

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, arcgis-python-api

I'm using python's requests and arcgis libraries for to query an open data endpoint for my county GIS data.   I'm trying to query the recent sales data within a 2 mile radius of an address.  I've worked out the sql "where" logic to get the "recent" results but can't seem to find a way to do the radius filter.  Here is what I've tried:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS 
from arcgis.geocoding import geocode, reverse_geocode 
from arcgis.geometry import Point 
from arcgis.features import *

gis=GIS()
address = "2526 westmoreland dr raleigh nc" 
wake_url = 'https://maps.wakegov.com/arcgis/rest/services/Property/Parcels/MapServer/0/'

address_geo = geocode(address = address, out_sr=102100)[0] 
address_geo
```

> {'address': 'Westmoreland Dr, Raleigh, North Carolina, 27612', 
>   'location': {'x': -8758500.574766971, 'y': 4276897.574964388}, 
>   'score': 94.81,  'attributes': {'Loc_name': 'World',   'Status': 'M', 
>   ......

This gets me a geocoded address.   Next, I try to query the feature layer:

```
requests_layer = FeatureLayer(wake_url)
```

Setup my SQL statemetn for my where clause:

```
from_date = dt.datetime.strptime('1/1/2016', '%m/%d/%Y')
sql = "SALE_DATE >= DATE '{}'".format(from_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
sql
```

> "SALE_DATE >= DATE '2016-01-01'"

Then perform my queries:

```
#how many total records are there?
requests_layer.query(return_count_only=True)
```

> 393540

Now, how many parcels have sold in last 4 years:

```
requests_layer.query(where=sql, return_count_only=True)
```

> 95117

All good so far as I now have filtered this down to just the parcels that sold recently across the whole county.  But I then get lost when I try to further reduce this to just the parcels within a radius of an address...     I have tried buffers, geometry_filter, etc.  Can't seem to find the right combo.  Example:

```
requests_layer.query(where=sql, return_count_only=True, geometry_filter=address_geo, distance=1, units='miles')
```

> 95117

This is a small subset of the county and the count should be much less.   What am I missing?

I've also played around with the endpoint REST API.  I"m not sure I understand what the geometry_filter is doing for me.

Comment: I was able to keep iterating through the rest endpoint to get this query string to work.  [query endpoint](https://maps.wakegov.com/arcgis/rest/services/Property/Parcels/MapServer/0/query?where=SALE_DATE%20%3E=%20DATE%20%272016-01-01%27&outFields=*&geometry=-78.727%2C35.790%2C-78.509%2C35.814&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=4326&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelContains&distance=1&units=esriSRUnit_StatuteMile&returnGeometry=false&outSR=4326&f=json&returnCountOnly=True)  .  Now need to code this up in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work as follows:

1) Iterate through the GIS rest endpoint here:  [GIS endpoint](http://data-wake.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/parcels/geoservice?geometry=-78.727%2C35.790%2C-78.509%2C35.814)

2) Was able to get this query string to work:  [working query string](https://maps.wakegov.com/arcgis/rest/services/Property/Parcels/MapServer/0/query?where=SALE_DATE%20%3E=%20DATE%20%272016-01-01%27&outFields=*&geometry=-78.727%2C35.790%2C-78.509%2C35.814&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=4326&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelContains&distance=1&units=esriSRUnit_StatuteMile&returnGeometry=false&outSR=4326&f=json&returnCountOnly=True)

After that, I developed an arguments dictionary which builds out query string:

```
radius = 1 #in miles
center = address_geo['location']   #lat/long of address of center of radius
spatial_radius_filter = dict(inSR=4326, 
                             outSR=4326,
                             return_geometry=False, 
                             geometryType="esriGeometryPoint", 
                             spatialRel="esriSpatialRelContains", 
                             geometry=center, 
                             supportsQueryWithDistance=True, 
                             distance=radius, 
                             units='esriSRUnit_StatuteMile')
```

And this returns the featureset:

```
features = requests_layer.query(where=sql, **spatial_radius_filter)
features.df
```

(Dataframe with results)